# Adding a Progress Bar from a simple copy to the C Drive

Tags: vb.net, copy, progress-bar, file-copying

I am using this code:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
            "Software\Service Packs\WindowsXP\SP2\WindowsXP-KB835935-SP2-ENU.exe",
            "C:\Service Pack\WindowsXP-KB835935-SP2-ENU.exe")

        Process.Start("C:\Service Pack\WindowsXP-KB835935-SP2-ENU.exe")
```

This simply copies Windows XP Service Pack from a pendrive to the C Drive located above.

I wish to add a Progress bar to the Form and need the code in order to do this.

Thank you,

Comment: Do you mean add a progress bar at runtime? You could add one to the designer, or just use something like this `Dim p as New ProgressBar()    p.Parent = Me`...etc.

Comment: As my above code is running, the program freezes while the code is executed. The code runs successfully and does as I wanted. But I just wanted to show the end user that the program is copying the file with the progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Drag a ProgressBar and Timer to the form.

Add the following code under `Timer1_Tick` event:

## Code And Example

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick () Handles Timer1.Tick
      ProgressBar1.Increment (20)
      If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum then
           Timer1.Stop
           'Add things here you want to do when progressbar reaches maximum.  
      End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load () Handles Mybase.Load
      Timer1.Stop
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click () Handles Button1.Click
      Timer1.Start
End Sub
```

## Explanation

The value specified in the `ProgressBar1.Increment` means the percentage of increase. It will stop increasing when the value is maximum.

The Statement `Timer1.Start` must be added to the event from which you want to trigger the `ProgressBar` (Not necessary to write under the `Form_Load` event).

*Hope it works perfectly.*

Comment: I did try exactly what you suggested but no luck in the program :(

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Is your timer enabled? Search in the properties of timer.

Comment: Timer is now enabled, auto hide made me forget about that. When the program is executed, the Progress Bar shoots right up to the top, but does nothing when the file is copied. My code above is executed when a button is clicked. I didn't get any errors because it thought it worked.