# How to update a progress bar while copying and pasting in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Hello Stack overflow community, I am here to get some help for a tool that I am programming in VB.net, I am using Visual Studio 2015 and what I am working on right now is a tool that basically creates a backup of a folder, it basically copies all files from a path that it's given in TextBox1 to the path that it's given in TextBox2, when the user presses the button "Create", it will execute this code:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, True)
```

It works perfectly but what I want to do is, the progress bar that I have added to be updated during the copy paste process so the user can know that it's actually working.

The whole code is here:

```
Public Class Form4

    Private Sub FolderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FolderBrowserDialog2_HelpRequest(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub FolderBrowserDialog1_Disposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToArray

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        FolderBrowserDialog2.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub FolderBrowserDialog2_Disposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        TextBox2.Text = FolderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath.ToArray

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, True)

        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Form3.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

If there's anything else that I haven't explained, let me know, thank you.

Comment: Set the progressbar style to marquee.  The only other way is to do it file by file so you can count what you are doing and report the progress.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting A Progress Bar Based On Directory Copy in Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303811/setting-a-progress-bar-based-on-directory-copy-in-visual-basic)

Comment: That code is not really copy-pasting though

Comment: Yeah,that title needs to be changed. The title makes it sounds like this has to do with the clipboard.